# Unit Testing Code Coverage for WebService Method including async methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, async-await, mstest

I just need information about code coverage of webservice method that includes Async Methods as well.

Suppose, I have one method written in WebService, `MethodOne(string Value)` and I have written `TestMethod` to check code coverage for this method,

When I run Test and check in code coverage, it showing me something like

`MethodOne(string)` 100%

`MethodOneAsync(string)` 0%

`MethodOneAsync(string,object)` 0%

so because of Asynchronous methods, I can not verify the actual code coverage of my projects, I want to cover these kind of methods as well in my code coverage.

I researched on google and read many articles but didn't get a valuable code, I have written following code as well but it doesn't help as well.

```
public async void TestMethod1Async()
{
    bool isValue = await System.Threading.Tasks.TaskEx.Run(() => target.IsAccountDisabled(Guid.NewGuid()));
    Assert.IsFalse(isValue);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write asynchronous unit tests to test asynchronous methods.

Asynchronous unit tests must be `async Task`.

Comment: You mean, I have to write two unit test, one for sync method and other one for async method.

Comment: If you want to test them both, then yes.